# How to lazily initialise FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay

Tags: android, android-jetpack, app-startup

I have noticed FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay is taking 500ms to load. I am trying to initialize it lazily. Below are the steps i did:

```
implementation "androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1"
```

Added startup library in gradle.

```
class FirebaseInAppMessageInitializer : Initializer<FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay> {
override fun create(context: Context): FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay {
    return FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay.getInstance()
}

override fun dependencies(): List<Class<out Initializer<*>>> {
    return emptyList()
}
}
```

Created an Initializer so i can initialize it lazily.

```
      <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="get.lokal.localnews.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="merge">
        <meta-data android:name="get.lokal.localnews.lazyinitializer.FirebaseInAppMessageInitializer"
            tools:node="remove" />
    </provider>
```

Added this provider tag in AndroidManifest. It disables the automatic intitiazation of the FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay library

```
 AppInitializer.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .initializeComponent(FirebaseInAppMessageInitializer.class);
```

called this in Application class but when checked in Android Profiler, this library is getting intialized before App.onCreate().

I have followed this documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup

Any kind of help or suggestion will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Did you solve this issue?